After upgrading to Xcode 16 I am stuck at "Waiting to reconnect to..." when trying to build to a device
After upgrading to Xcode 16 from the latest Xcode 15 I am having trouble building to my Apple TV on tvOS 17.7 (I have an older model that connects via USB-C which eliminates network connectivity issues.) But I get stuck with the following when I go to the "Devices and Simulators" window:

Previous preparation error: Failed to find a DDI that can be used to
enable DDI services on the device. Usually this means the best DDI we
could find for a platform did not have compatible CoreDevice content.
Run ‘devicectl list preferredDDI’ from the command line to get more
details on why no valid DDI can be found.

When I run xcrun devicectl list preferredDDI I get:
WARNING: No usable DDI found for the tvOS platform (The DDI's CoreDevice content is too old.). Best (unusable) DDI found is:
• hostDDI: file:///Library/Developer/DeveloperDiskImages/tvOS_DDI.dmg
▿ ddiMetadata:
    • buildUpdate: 15F31d
    • contentIsCompatible: false
    • coreDeviceVersionChecksIncludeDevelopmentRevision: true
    • developmentRevision: 0
    • enforcingCoreDeviceVersionChecks: true
    • platform: tvOS
    ▿ projectMetadata:
        • Citrine-25.1.1
        • CoreDevice-355.28
        • DTDeveloperDiskImageSupport-14.0.0
        • DTOCMock-22600
        • GPUToolsDevice_DDI-270.8
        • JetsamProperties-1925.120.11
        • LiveExecutionResultsLogger-19506
        • Mercury-49
        • XCTest-22720
    • incompatibleContentReason: The DDI's CoreDevice content is too old.
    • isUsable: false
    • variant: external

I've tried:

Ensuring I am the latest macOS (but sticking to 14.x Sonoma for now)
xcode-select --switch /path/to/new/Xcode
Installing the latest platform and simulator components via Xcode > Settings > Components
Upgrading tvOS from 17.7 to 18
Disabling defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTEnableCoreDevice disable that I recall enabling for Xcode 15
Deleting /Library/Developer/DeveloperDiskImages/ in attempt to re-trigger it
Ensuring the latest Xcode Command Line Tools were installed
Restarting Xcode and also my computer

None of these steps worked! Note that when I upgraded to macOS 14.7 I did get this prompt: "A software update is required to connect" but I received an "Installation failed" with "Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server". Perhaps because I am using a work-owned laptop with managed software updates.

The Short
What worked for me is running xcrun devicectl manage ddis update
I was able to verify this worked by running xcrun devicectl list preferredDDI which gave me the following:
The DDI used for the tvOS platform:
• hostDDI: file:///Library/Developer/DeveloperDiskImages/tvOS_DDI.dmg
▿ ddiMetadata:
    • buildUpdate: 16A242d
    • contentIsCompatible: true
    • coreDeviceVersionChecksIncludeDevelopmentRevision: true
    • developmentRevision: 0
    • enforcingCoreDeviceVersionChecks: true
    • platform: tvOS
    ▿ projectMetadata:
        • Citrine-94
        • CoreDevice-397.21
        • DTDeveloperDiskImageSupport-14.0.0
        • DTOCMock-23002
        • GPUToolsDevice_DDI-300.21
        • JetsamProperties-2205
        • LiveExecutionResultsLogger-20002
        • Mercury-54
        • XCTest-23196
    • isUsable: true
    • variant: external

(Notice the buildUpdate references Xcode 16 instead of 15.)
I restarted Xcode to be sure, and it worked after downloading device data
The Long
Xcode 16 expanded upon DDI -- I assume "Developer Disk Image" -- that would have been first introduced in Xcode 15:

With iOS 17+, we are using a new device stack (CoreDevice) to
communicate with devices. With this new device stack, there is one DDI
per platform (as opposed to per OS release). This same device stack
will be shared across all versions of Xcode on your system, and
installing a newer version of Xcode will update CoreDevice and its
DDIs.
Source: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/730947

Xcode 16 release notes mention that:

devicectl now provides commands to manage the developer disk images present on your Mac.

So I assume this is a bug with Xcode.

Very good Q&A pair. Likely to be useful to others!

How did you install Xcode 16?  Did you run xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch or launch Xcode.app first?  That is required before launching Xcode.app.  xcrun devicectl will trigger that for you, which is why it fixed things for you.

@JeremyHuddlestonSequoia My issue was building to device via the Xcode 16 GUI, so I had certainly already launched Xcode 16. I saw the first launch prompt and downloaded the "additional platforms". I don't see why end-users need to know to run a CLI command, unless you're talking about running Xcode headless?
But I did download and install Xcode via https://github.com/XcodesOrg/XcodesApp (version 1.10.0) -- I do recall it had trouble with running the "make active" switching of Xcode versions using that tool

Not sure about the "XcodesApp" thing, but if you launched Xcode.app directly, it should have run xcrun devicectl manage ddis update as part of that first launch experience.  It's actually done as part of the post_install script for the XcodeSystemResources.pkg package that is installed during that process.  Does the /var/log/install.log for the system you saw this on happen to go back far enough to when that package was installed?  Are there any errors reported during that post install script?

@JeremyHuddlestonSequoia To eye I don't see any obvious errors for XcodeSystemResources.pkg in my /var/log/install.log though I do see a record if it being extracted. I have uploaded a copy of my log my Apple bug report FB15243080
Are these anything?
system_installd[1662]: preinstall: Unload failed: 5: Input/output error
system_installd[1662]: preinstall: Error Domain=KMErrorDomain Code=71 "Could not find: No bundle was found at //Library/Apple/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.dt.RemotePairingDataVaultHelper.plist."

Interesting.  I don't see our postinstall script running there.  I see the postinstall script for MobileDevice.pkg, but not XcodeSystemResources.pkg.  I'd really like to know what went wrong, but unfortunately any otehr breadcrumbs in the system log are long since purged =/  If you see this again, pleaes promptly grab a sysdiagnose afte the installation failure, so I can take a look!

Great solution! Previously I was removing the Library/Developer directory and have Xcode install everything again.

I also encountered that problem after downloading Xcode via the Xcodes.app and also downloading iOS and watchOS SDKs via Xcodes.app.
